# Realm Swift: Object has been deleted or invalidated

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a tableViewController (ArticlesVC) that displays an array of Articles that are fetched from an API. Each of these tableViewCell has a "more action" button that allows the user to save the article for later reading in the SavedVC. Note that only saved articles are written to Realm DB, the displaying of articles in the ArticlesVC are not written to Realm DB.

If the user has saved the article, I would show "Remove saved article", otherwise, I show "Save for later". I query Realm to conduct this check.

However, if I delete a saved article (or all saved articles) from Realm from SavedVC and go back to the ArticlesVC and start swiping the tableView, it crashes with the above error. This crash happens on an intermittent basis, making it pretty hard to pinpoint.

Code

```
//At ArticlesVC, where articles are fetched via API
func getArticles() {
    AF.request(apiUrl).responseJSON { (response) in
        //Error checks and decoding ...

        self.articles = try decoder.decode(Article.self, from: data)
    }
} 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ArticleCell
    cell.article = articles[indexPath.row]
    cell.moreButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.moreButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moreButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return cell
}

@objc func moreButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let buttonTag = sender.tag
    let article = articles[buttonTag]

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "More", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let action = getAction(article: article)
    alert.addActions([action, .cancelAction()])
    //present alert
}


func getAction(article: Article) -> UIAlertAction {

    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        let articleInRealm = realm.objects(Article.self).filter("id == %@", article.id)

        if articleInRealm.isInvalidated {
            return UIAlertAction(title: "Save for later", style: .default, handler: {(_) in
                self.saveArticle(article: article)
            })
        } else {
            if articleInRealm.count == 0 {
                return UIAlertAction(title: "Save for later", style: .default, handler: {(_) in
                    self.saveArticle(article: article)
                })
            } else {
                return UIAlertAction(title: "Remove saved article", style: .destructive, handler: {(_) in
                    self.deleteArticle(article: articleInRealm)
                })
            }
        }


    } catch {
        Log("Err getting article: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return UIAlertAction(title: "Save for later", style: .default, handler: {(_) in
            self.saveArticle(article: article)
        })
    }
}

func saveArticle(article: Article) {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()

        try realm.write {
            realm.add(article, update: .modified)
        }

    } catch {
        Log("Err saving article: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func deleteArticle(article: Results<Article>) {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()

        try realm.write {
            realm.delete(article)
        }

    } catch {
        Log("Err saving article: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

//At SavedVC, which is another VC in the tabBarController. 
//ArticlesVC is in tab1 and SavedVC is in tab2
var notificationToken: NotificationToken? = nil
var articles: Results<Article>?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    subscribeToRealmNotifications()
}

fileprivate func subscribeToRealmNotifications() {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let results = realm.objects(Article.self)

    notificationToken = results.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in

        guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }

        switch changes {
            case .initial:

                self?.articles = results

                tableView.reloadData()

            case .update(_, _, _, _):
                tableView.reloadData()

            case .error(let error):
                fatalError("Realm notif: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

My guess is that because I have deleted the articles in SavedVC but ArticlesVC is still pointing to those Realm objects which no longer exist and therefore crashed.

I have read multiple SO posts that suggest to do a check on `obj.isInvalidated`, which I did and have included a condition for it. But this still crashes.

Other attempts includes:

- using `realm.create()` instead of `realm.add()`

Comment: A couple of things. Realm Results objects are Live updating lists - if an object is deleted from Realm, it will also be removed that that results list. This function definition is a little troubling `func deleteArticle(article: Results<Article>)` as if you're intending to delete a single article, why pass in a results object which could technically be more than one object?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue: You've saving an unmanaged object (article) into realm

```
func getAction(article: Article)
    ...
    self.saveArticle(article: article)
```

which then makes it a managed object.

If it's deleted from Realm,

```
realm.delete(article)
```

it will also be removed from the results object that contains it

```
articles[indexPath.row]
```

Which will then make your app crash as it's scrolling as the dataSource and tableView are out of sync.

I have a feeling you don't want it to actually be removed from the master list of articles.

My suggestion is to save any articles you want to read later by their id which will have no effect on the master list of articles as they are added and removed from realm.

In other words your master list of articles stays the same but in Realm, you have a table of id's which are strings for example. So when you want to track what they want to read

```
self.saveArticleId(article: article.id)
```

and then when it's time to delete it from their saved reading list

```
self.deleteArticleBy(articleId: artical.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I would like to clarify that the master list of articles are not Realm objects, ie articles in the master list are `[Article]()` instead of `Results<Article>`. They are simply returned from the API and listed, not managed through Realm. Only those articles that the users wanna save to read later are managed through Realm. This shouldn't affect the `articles[indexPath.row]` right?

Comment: Also, saving by `articleId` to Realm would imply that there is a need to make another API call to fetch the articles data, which is not what we want. We want to make the articles accessible offline and hence the implementation with Realm.

Comment: @Koh um... If it's not a realm object, then how are you saving it to Realm? If you look at the flow, the code passes a non-realm `Article` object to `func getAction(article: Article)`. Then that same non-realm `Article` object is passed to `self.saveArticle(article: article)` where then it's saved to realm `realm.add(article, update: .modified)`. So... ?

Comment: @Koh and to answer the question in your comment with a question...How are the saved articles being displayed to the user so they know they are saved? In other words, what sequence happens when a user wants to read a saved article? Suppose they have 100 of them. Are you displaying the full contents of every article in a mile-long list or is it just snippet of the first sentence or perhaps an article title? Then, when they select which article to read, what happens next? This is going a bit OT but the answer will depend on that information. Let's fix the initial issue first.

Comment: thanks for your response. Yes, after `realm.add(article, update: .modified)`, we show a successful saved popup. The saved articles will be displayed in another tableView (SavedVC). I have added the code to show how saved articles are read from Realm in SavedVC. Basically we will show key info in a tableView in SavedVC, ie titles, publishing date, imageView etc, and when users tap on the article, it pushes to a detailVC to show the full article's content. Our designer's intent was to make SavedVC completely offline.

Comment: @Koh Great. We address that separately but answering the main question is the big issue now. If Article isn't a Realm object, how are you saving it to Realm? By all indicators in the code `realm.add(article, update: .modified)`, Article *is* a Realm object that's being observed/in a list/in results and when it's deleted, the object is removed from that/those lists causing the crash.

Comment: Yes, Articles in SavedVC are realm objects, but Articles in ArticlesVC are not realm objects, or at least they were simply listed right after receiving it from the API. Basically if I open up the realm file, the Articles in the realm file are only those that are saved by the user. Also, the crash isn't at the SavedVC but at the ArticlesVC, which isn't reading off realm when listing the articles in ArticlesVC. It reads realm only when users tap on the more button. This is the part that I am confused.

Comment: @Koh Take another look at your code; *but Articles in ArticlesVC are not realm objects* is not accurate so let me try this a different way. Swift apps cannot have two Objects with the same name. In ArticlesVC, you're using an object called Article. In SavedVC, you're also using an object called Article. Along with that, in SavedVC, you're directly saving the Article object to Realm. Therefore, Article *must* be a Realm object, otherwise it could not be saved. This `self.articles = try decoder.decode(Article.self, from: data)` creates a Realm object, and if deleted, causes the error.

Comment: I see. On your note about `self.articles = try decoder.decode(Article.self, from: data)` creating a realm object, and if deleted causing the crash, do you mean that **even if** the object is not commited in a write transaction, ie `realm.write{}`, it will still crash?

Comment: @Koh This wraps back around to my answer. You're adding unmanaged Articles to a Realm List. When they are saved, they then become managed objects. If the object is deleted from realm, it's then *removed from the results* and cannot be accessed, so when scrolling, the app will crash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215029/discussion-between-koh-and-jay).